# Give min and max time for timepicker in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How to give min and max time for timepicker in Xamarin forms

```
picker_time = new TimePicker
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,

    Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Add(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0)),
    //WidthRequest = 100,
};
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use [XLabs ExtendedTimePicker](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/ExtendedTimePicker.cs) to set minimum time and maximum time

Answer (score -3):

```
<DatePicker x:Name="xDate" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Date="{Binding ExpenseDate}" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >


 xDate.SetValue (DatePicker.MaximumDateProperty, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: this is for datepicker.i want for timepicker